# Making a inserted image draggable js

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm working on a website where you have a list of images, when you click on one of these images it will appear in the field this part works as shown in the code below.

now the images that are put on this field should be able to be dragged around everywhere in the div field and I cant quite figure out how to do this while also making it so you can put more images in the div.

```
     const insertImage = (line) => {        
        var container = document.getElementById("field");
        var childElemnent = document.createElement("img");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        childElemnent.src = line.src
        childElemnent.id = line.alt
        childElemnent.tabindex = 1
        childElemnent.onkeypress  = function() { removeAddedElement(this.id) }
        container.appendChild(childElemnent);
        document.body.veld.appendChild(div);
    }
```

Comment: Try sortable.js

Comment: from what I see online this is just for making a list, maybe I didn't specify enough but I want to have a large div where images can be moved anywhere within this this div.

Comment: https://sortablejs.github.io/Sortable/ Check the examples for grids. You can drag any div anywhere in the parent div and that div can have anything. For you it would be img. I used it to make draggable charts in a dashboard.

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for since I want less restrictive movement and the ability to have images closer to each other

Comment: Like a puzzle basically? Well if you make it from scratch then you might face many issues. I'm just sharing my experience. You will be needing draggable=true with mouse events. Anyways good luck

Answer (score 0):

i found a solution

```
     const insertImage = (line) => {        
        var container = document.getElementById("veld");
        var childElemnent = document.createElement("img");
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        childElemnent.src = line.src
        childElemnent.id = line.alt
        childElemnent.className = line.alt
        // childElemnent.tabindex = 1
        container.appendChild(childElemnent);
        $( ".Matje" ).draggable()
       
    }
```